# Creating an insert function in a BST in C++

Tags: c++, insert, binary-search-tree

I want to write an insert function to create a node in BST but struggling with one of the tests. Here's the instruction for the lab
"Using the class skeleton definition below, write the insert method that inserts that create a new BST node that will be used for an integer Binary Search Tree (BST). The two constructors must be functioning in your class so please make sure you have the earlier assignments working or you will not get credit for this assignment".

Below is the current version of my code with the constructors already working:

```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

class BST
{
  public:
  int data;
  BST *left, *right;
  int nth_node(int n);
  

     BST(){
        data = 0;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
     }
     BST(int value){}
  


    void insert(int value){
    BST* root;
    if(root == NULL){
        BST* root = new BST;
            root->data = value;
            root->left = NULL;
            root->right == NULL;
            return;
   }
    else if(value < root->data){
            
              root->left->insert(value);}

    else if(value > root->data){
            
         root->right->insert(value);
            
    }
    else{
        cout <<"The key" <<value<< "exists\n";
        }
    }
 };
```

When I run this code, I get this error message
"Test Failed: 'Failed right child test' != 'Passed All Tests'

- Failed right child test

- Passed All Tests
  .

Comment: In your `insert()` function, `root` is a local variable. You likely don't want that. I think when you call insert, you should call it on the node you consider current root. Also, your `BST(int value)` ctor doesn't do anything with value, that seems like an issue. In general, suggest writing your own unit tests.

Comment: `BST* root; if(root == NULL)` -- This code will not work, even if you meant to make `root` a local variable The `root` is uninitialized, thus there is no guarantee `root` is `NULL`.

Comment: This is all wrong. Your BST class is not a tree, it's a node in a tree.. You want one class for the nodes and another class for the tree. Your confusion over where the root of the tree belongs is evidence that the design is wrong.

Comment: If you are really being asked to work with the class design you have here then you are being taught by someone who has a shaky understanding of class design. More likely (I guess) is that you've simply misunderstood what you've been asked to do.

Comment: As for why this class is all wrong: How do you represent the empty tree with your class? And for your 2 constructors: delete them and write `int data = 0; BST *left = nullptr, *right = nullptr;`.